# Perl script to batch equivalent

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, perl

I created a PERL file, but as it's rather simpistic, seems a little 'overkill' to send people 16MB of PERL on a USB stick just to run one program, so wondering if a smaller DOS batch file could work.(I know the most important part -EXIFTOOL - can be run from CMD. (I'll include the code anon)

Here is the time txt file:

```
ABC|10:15
DEF|10:30
XYZ|10:40
```

The script loads the photos, puts them into numeric order,(rather than 1, 10 ,2, 20 that basic sort gives) and, using EXIF, finds when the photo was taken. It takes top two values off the file. "If time > A && time < B move to folder" So a timestamp of 10:16, 10:20, 10:25 gets moved to ABC.

However, 10:33 timestamp is above B... so it makes B the new A, and gets next time off text file (10:40) So now it moves any timestamp between 10:30 and 10:40 to folder DEF. (I add a dummy entry to the end of the time file so the X+1 doesn't try to read past end of file. The loop is set to @data-1. So if file is 12 lines long, it loops through to 11, and reads x+1 from dummy line at end... which is NOW, and no photos will have that timestamp)

**Do you reckon these loops / read directories / if statements could be condensed into a simple batch file?**

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl

    use v5.10;
    use strict;
    use warnings;
my $photoFolder='../../EventsSoft/photos';
use Image::ExifTool;
use File::Copy;
use Time::Local;

### IMPORTANT ###
my $mainFolder='AHS_school';
### IMPORTANT ###

if (!defined $mainFolder || $mainFolder eq ''){
mkdir $photoFolder.'/temp';
$mainFolder='temp';
}
elsif (not -e $photoFolder.'/'.$mainFolder){
mkdir $photoFolder.'/'.$mainFolder;
}


my $exif=new Image::ExifTool;
my ($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year,$wday,$yday,$isdst,$currentFile,$nextFile,$barcode,$dummy);
my @timePic;
my @checkPics;

opendir my $ht, $photoFolder or die "Could not open photo folder for reading '$!'\n";
my @ht = grep {/\.jpg$/} readdir $ht;           # Only keep the JPG files
closedir $ht;

@checkPics = map  { $_->[0] }               # Sorts the files so run 1,2,3 not 1,11,12
             sort { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] }
             map  { [$_, $_=~/(\d+)/] } @ht;

for (my $x=0; $x<@checkPics; $x++){
$exif->ExtractInfo($photoFolder.'/'.'photo'.$x.'.jpg');
$timePic[$x]=$exif->GetValue('CreateDate');
}

open (my $fh, '<', $photoFolder.'/photog1.dat') or die "Could not open photog1.dat for reading '$!'\n";
my @data=<$fh>;
close($fh);
chomp @data;

($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year,$wday,$yday,$isdst) = localtime(time);
    if ($mon eq 11){
    $mon=0;
    }
    else{
    $mon++;
    }
my $str = sprintf ("%02d:%02d %02d:%02d:%02d", $mon, $mday, $hour, $min, $sec);
my $fakeTime='XXXXXX|'.($year+1900).':'.$str;
push (@data,$fakeTime); # Saves time in ISO format

# @data holds the time barcode scanned in the format XXXAGK|2019-03-15 11:14:00
# @checkPics holds the image filename
# @timePic holds time photo was taken
# The fake entry stops reading beyond end of file with ($y+1) option below. Np photos would have been taken at this time/date


for (my $x=0; $x<@data-1; $x++){
($barcode,$currentFile)=split('\|',$data[$x]);      # Gets the top value off data, and gets the barcode
($dummy,$nextFile)=split('\|',$data[($x+1)]);       # Gets the next value down - files to be below this value
    for (my $y=0;$y<@timePic; $y++){
        if ($timePic[$y] eq 0){
        next;
        }
        if ($timePic[$y] lt $nextFile){
        mkdir $photoFolder.'/'.$mainFolder.'/'.$barcode;
        copy ($photoFolder.'/'.$checkPics[$y], $photoFolder.'/'.$mainFolder.'/'.$barcode.'/'.$checkPics[$y]) or die "Copy failed line 70 '$!'\n";
        $timePic[$y]=0;
        }
        if ($timePic[$y] gt $nextFile){
        last;
        }
    }
}

## Because the above loop is @data-1; we do not get to the last entry, so need one final loop
my $picEnd=@data;
($barcode,$dummy)=split('\|',$data[$picEnd-2]); # Gets the final barcode
    for (my $y=0;$y<@timePic; $y++){
        if ($timePic[$y] eq 0){
        next;
        }
        mkdir $photoFolder.'/'.$mainFolder.'/'.$barcode;
        copy ($photoFolder.'/'.$checkPics[$y], $photoFolder.'/'.$mainFolder.'/'.$barcode.'/'.$checkPics[$y]) or die "Copy failed line 86'$!'\n";
    }
if ($mainFolder eq 'temp'){
rename $photoFolder.'/temp',$photoFolder.'/!! TEMP !!'; 
}

say "All photos have been moved to their respective folders";
```

Comment: I'm not versed enough in perl to fully understand your script, but IMO it should be easier to translate to PowerShell as cmd.exe lacks a datetime data type. Where do you obtain the barcode from?

Comment: My other program uses Imager, to which I give it a number, and it draws a PNG of a barcode.I then use a library called PDF:API2 that pulls in allthe graphics, and lays them out in a 3x8 label format. So basically, I can feed it any of the 8,000 letter combinations, and it can print out 8,000 individual labels ! (Even though each person gets 50 -300 cards, I can give the same card /label to (say) 10 ~ 20 differnt people

Comment: I have looked at powershell (briefly) and that seems even more complex than the archaic DOS

Comment: (I've also found a site that lists all the DOS commands,so I might be able to wor it out given time !)

Comment: IMO PowerShell syntax is more like Perl than CMD, a well received source for both script languages is [ss64.com](https://ss64.com)

Comment: Cheers LotPings.Will check that resource out